# How Do I use htmlspecialchars but allow only specific HTML code to pass through without getting converted?

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

Here is the line of code I have which works great:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($_POST['content'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

But what I would like to do is allow only certain types of HTML code to pass through without getting converted. Here is the list of HTML code that I would like to have pass:

```
<pre> </pre>
<b> </b>
<em> </em>
<u> </u>
<ul> </ul>
<li> </li>
<ol> </ol>
```

And as I go, I would like to also be able to add in more HTML later as I think of it. Could someone help me modify the code above so that the specified list of HTML codes above can pass through without getting converted?

Comment: Htmlspecialchars doesn't look at html, it looks at characters `<`, `>`, etc and escapes them. So you cannot do it with htmlspecialchars... maybe [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)?

Comment: You cannot. But you could convert constrained whitelisted tags back afterwards, `&lt;em&gt;` to `<em>` for example.

Answer (score 14):

I suppose you could do it after the fact:

```
// $str is the result of htmlspecialchars()
preg_replace('#&lt;(/?(?:pre|b|em|u|ul|li|ol))&gt;#', '<\1>', $str);
```

It allows the encoded version of `<xx>` and `</xx>` where `xx` is in a controlled set of allowed tags.

Comment: If you also want to allow things like `<u class="...">`, `<img src="...">` or `<a href="...">` you just need to change the pattern string to `'#&lt;(/?(?:pre|b|em|u|ul|li|ol)(?:.*?)?)&gt;#'`

Comment: @Adam What if you wanted the href to contain a certain string so not any site could be linked?

Comment: @TheWelshManc for that kind of control it would be advisable to use a proper html processor

Comment: It’s okay I managed to get it to work, I checked to see if it had a very specific string in the url and only then would it allow the href

Comment: @TheWelshManc You have to be careful with that, say you are looking for `example.com` whats to stop someone from putting this in `google.com?example.com`. it would still link to google.com but depending on how you are looking for example.com would probably still pass. the only way to do it is to make sure the URL starts with `https://example.com`

Answer (score 6):

Or you can go with old style:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($_POST['content'], ENT_QUOTES);

$turned = array( '&lt;pre&gt;', '&lt;/pre&gt;', '&lt;b&gt;', '&lt;/b&gt;', '&lt;em&gt;', '&lt;/em&gt;', '&lt;u&gt;', '&lt;/u&gt;', '&lt;ul&gt;', '&lt;/ul&gt;', '&lt;li&gt;', '&lt;/li&gt;', '&lt;ol&gt;', '&lt;/ol&gt;' );
$turn_back = array( '<pre>', '</pre>', '<b>', '</b>', '<em>', '</em>', '<u>', '</u>', '<ul>', '</ul>', '<li>', '</li>', '<ol>', '</ol>' );

$content = str_replace( $turned, $turn_back, $content );
```

Comment: I think this (for a small amount of tags and content) could be actually much more faster :)

Comment: @jave.web Very much agreed!

Answer (score 2):

I improved the way Jack attacks this issue. I added support for `<br>, <br/>` and anchor tags. The code will replace fist `href=&quot;...&quot;` to allow only this attribute to be used.

```
$str = preg_replace(
    array('#href=&quot;(.*)&quot;#', '#&lt;(/?(?:pre|a|b|br|em|u|ul|li|ol)(\shref=".*")?/?)&gt;#' ), 
    array( 'href="\1"', '<\1>' ), 
    $str
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made this function to sanitize all HTML special characters except for the HTML tags specified.

It first uses htmlspecialchars() to make the string safe, then it reverts the tags I want to be untouched.

The function supports attribute filtering as an option, however be careful to disable it if you care about possible XSS attacks.

I know regex is not efficient but for moderate string lengths it should be fine.
You can check the regex I used here 
https://regex101.com/r/U6GQse/8

```
public function sanitizeHtml($string, $safeHtmlTags = array('b','i','u','br'), $filterAttributes = true)
{
    $string = htmlspecialchars($string);

    if ($filterAttributes) {
        $replace = "<$1$2$4>";
    } else {
        $replace = "<$1$2$3$4>";
    }
    $string = preg_replace("/&lt;\s*(\/?\s*)(".implode("|", $safeHtmlTags).")(\s?|\s+[\s\S]*?)(\/)?\s*&gt;/", $replace, $string);

    return $string;
}

// Example usage to answer the OP question
$str = "MY HTML CONTENT"
echo sanitizeHtml($str, array('pre','b','em','u','ul','li','ol'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked Elwin's solution, but you probably want to:

1. Prevent Javascript: URL's in the `href` - or more likely: allow only `http(s)`.
2. Make the regex globs non-greedy in case there are multiple `<a href>`'s in the content.

Here is the updated version:

```
$str = preg_replace(
    array('#href=&quot;(https?://.*?)&quot;#', '#&lt;(/?(?:pre|a|b|br|em|u|ul|li|ol)(\shref=".*?")?/?)&gt;#' ), 
    array( 'href="\1"', '<\1>' ), 
    $str
);
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use strip_tags

```
$exceptionString = '<pre>,</pre>,<b>,</b>,<em>,</em>,<u>,</u>,<ul>,</ul>,<li>,</li>,<ol>,</ol>';

$content = strip_tags($_POST['content'],$exceptionString );
```

Comment: That's not exactly what OP is asking for.