# Combining htmlspecialchars and strip_tags

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

So I'm wanting to combine the functionality of  htmlspecialchars and strip_tags.

The elements I have so far are:

```
<form>
....
<section contenteditable="true" placeholder="Please enter your text content here..." class="content" id="content" name="content" type="text" cols="30" rows="10"></section>
....
</form>
```

This is then submitted

```
....
$content = $_POST['content'];
```

...Some SQL...

```
$content = $c['content'];
$new = htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES);
```

I wanting to combine htmlspecialchars and strip_tags together, they both work separately and produce the right result.

```
$new = strip_tags($content, '<code><b><i>');
....
```

So and example would be that this tag:

```
<section>
```

would be displayed as plain text where as this tag:

```
<code>
```

would be formatted correctly.

Comment: Have you tried, $content = str_ireplace(["<",">"], ["&lt;","&gt;"], $content);

Comment: So I figured it out, by browsing stackoverflow some more and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819804/how-do-i-use-htmlspecialchars-but-allow-only-specific-html-code-to-pass-through)

Comment: almost same as what I told you :P &lt; and &gt; lol... Okay Pal Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, maybe put it in a function:

```
$allowed = strip_tags($content, '<code><b><i>');

$content = htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES);

$content = str_replace(htmlspecialchars($allowed, ENT_QUOTES), $allowed, $content);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819804/how-do-i-use-htmlspecialchars-but-allow-only-specific-html-code-to-pass-through)