# PHP Display Image in htmlspecialchars Exception

Tags: php, html

I have PHP function to display all `HTML` code.

Example :

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars("<p>Welcome</p>"); ?>
```

Then the result will `<p>Welcome</p>`

Now I need to display image `<img src="http://nl3.php.net/images/logo.php"/>`, but it will display the code too `<img src="http://nl3.php.net/images/logo.php"/>`

How can I display the image?

Comment: Don't escape it. Are you basically saying you have HTML and some of that HTML you want escaped and others you do not? That's quite messy. You'll need a good selective sanitation library for that. Look at http://htmlpurifier.org and customise its rules so it escapes everything except image tags.

Comment: Check [this][1] post, it might help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819804/how-do-i-use-htmlspecialchars-but-allow-only-specific-html-code-to-pass-through

Comment: @deceze you should write that as an answer, for it is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

**Code desription**

Code will find every image tags `<img attr1=value1 attr2=value2 ... />` in text, create for every image own image tag with `new HtmlElement()` - this class is just custom light version of `new DOMElement()`, replace original image tag with placeholder, after every image is replace with placeholder, in this case I choose this placeholder `{#@#IMG_' . $id .'}` which is enough original for me type of texts , then will use on whole text `htmlspecialchars()` function and at the end it will replace placeholders with newly created image tags and return text back.

**Code explanation**

`if (preg_match_all('#<img\s+([^>]+?)\s?(/>|>)#i', $text, $matches)) {` Check if text contain any images, if yes, variabale `$matches` will contain 3 dimensional array of arrays, which will look like this for example:

```
array (3)
   0 => array (6)
   |  0 => "<img alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes" />"
   |  1 => "<img alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes" />"
   |  2 => "<img alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes" />"
   |  3 => "<img alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes" />"
   |  4 => "<img alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes" />"
   |  5 => "<img alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes" />"
   1 => array (6)
   |  0 => "alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes"" 
   |  1 => "alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes"" 
   |  2 => "alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes"" 
   |  3 => "alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes"" 
   |  4 => "alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes"" 
   |  5 => "alt="rolleyes" src="//t.domain.com/default/rolleyes.gif" title="rolleyes"" 
   2 => array (6)
   |  0 => "/>"
   |  1 => "/>"
   |  2 => "/>"
   |  3 => "/>"
   |  4 => "/>"
   |  5 => "/>"
```

then it create own images based on original `<img />` attributes and store them in varibale `$images`

```
foreach ($matches[1] as $id => $imgAttributes) {
    $img = new \HtmlElement('img');
    $img->addAttributes($imgAttributes);
    $img->attributes([
        'src' => $img->attr('src'),
        'alt' => escapeHtml($img->attr('alt')),
        'title' => escapeHtml($img->attr('title'))
    ]);
    $images[$id] = $img->render();
```

in my case i just need attributes `alt`, `title` and `src` from images, also if you don't need use escape HTML in attributes like `alt`, `title` or others, you can omit this part of code and witch little alterations continue with next code row:

```
$text = str_replace($matches[0][$id], '{#@#IMG_' . $id .'}', $text);
```

which will replace in original text every image tag with placeholder `'{#@#IMG_' . $id .'}'`, so for exmaple first image will be replaced in original text like:

```
{#@#IMG_0}
```

Keep in mind placeholder should be enough original for your type of texts and also can't contain any special characters which would be replaced with `htmlspecialchars()` for HTML entities.

When every image is replaced by own placeholder then we can convert special characters to HTML entities in whole text:

```
$text = escapeHtml($text);
```

and as last step we replace placeholders in text with image tags:

```
foreach ($images as $id => $image) {
    $text = str_replace('{#@#IMG_' . $id . '}', $image, $text);
}
```

**Whole code**

```
function escapeHtml($text)
{
   return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
}
function escapeHtmlKeepImages($text)
{
   if (preg_match_all('#<img\s+([^>]+?)\s?(/>|>)#i', $text, $matches)) {
      $images = [];
      foreach ($matches[1] as $id => $imgAttributes) {
            $img = new \HtmlElement('img');
            $img->addAttributes($imgAttributes);
            $img->attributes([
               'src' => $img->attr('src'),
               'alt' => escapeHtml($img->attr('alt')),
               'title' => escapeHtml($img->attr('title'))
            ]);
            $images[$id] = $img->render();
            $text = str_replace($matches[0][$id], '{#@#IMG_' . $id .'}', $text);
        }
        $text = escapeHtml($text);
        foreach ($images as $id => $image) {
            $text = str_replace('{#@#IMG_' . $id . '}', $image, $text);
        }
    } else {
        $text = escapeHtml($text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

**Version where you don't need treat attributes `alt`, `title` and others, with example**

```
$text = '
<strong>hello</strong>
<img src="image.gif" alt="something" >><3
how are you?
<img src="signature.gif" alt="signature"  title="signature"/>
';

function  escapeHtml($text)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
}
function escapeHtmlKeepImages($text)
{
    if (preg_match_all('#<img\s+([^>]+?)\s?(/>|>)#i', $text, $matches)) {
        array_map(
            function ($id, $img) use (&$text) {
                $text = str_replace($img, '{#@#IMG_' . $id . '}', $text);
            },
            array_keys($matches[0]), $matches[0]
        );

        $text = escapeHtml($text);

        array_map(
            function ($id, $img) use (&$text) {
                $text = str_replace('{#@#IMG_' . $id . '}', $img, $text);
            },
            array_keys($matches[0]), $matches[0]
        );
    } else {
        $text = escapeHtml($text);
    }
    return $text;

}

echo escapeHtmlKeepImages($text);
```

output:

```
&lt;strong&gt;hello&lt;/strong&gt;
<img src="image.gif" alt="something" >&gt;&lt;3
how are you?
<img src="signature.gif" alt="signature"  title="signature"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am a beginner in PHP and html too.
Let me try to solve this problem.

As we can see the result of "welcome", you can change to

```
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars("Welcome"); ?></p>
```

It will shows "Welcome" only. We can use the same method to handle the  as

```
    <img <?php echo htmlspecialchars("src='http://nl3.php.net/images/logo.php");?>/>
```

Although it is not a good programming style, you can solve the problem first and study the preg_match() later. Cheers!